# Disable the submit button for the default Dropdown value in an angular 2 Form

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a select  country dropdown which has a default value called "Select". There is a submit button at the bottom of the page which should get enabled only when the dropdown has some country values. For default value, the button should be disabled as it a mandatory field.

I have created a component for the dropdown in my .ts file.

```
@component({

selector:'country-component',
template:'<form>
<select>
<option [disabled]="butDisabled">Select</option>
<option [value]="" *ngFor="let country of countryList">{{country.label}}</option>
</select>
</form>'

})

export class countryComponent implements onInit{
butDisabled: boolean = true;
}
```

In my html-

```
<country-component (ngModelOptions)="{standalone:true}" name=""></country-component>

<button>Submit</button>
```

This does not work.It makes the entire dropdown disabled. Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Where is the button definition?  I see two options.

Comment: @John Baird See the updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let your parent component know when a country is selected.

Define a output parameter from your `country-component`

add import

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

And add your output parameter

```
export class countryComponent implements onInit{
    @output countrySelected = new EventEmitter(); // <-- define output parameter
}
```

You need to emit that output when a country is selected. Add following function to your `country-component`

```
onChange(selectedCountry) {
    this.countrySelected.emit(selectedCountry); // <-- emit when a country selected
}
```

Also you need to make a change on your select to call your new `onChange` function

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option [value]="" *ngFor="let country of countryList">{{country.label}</option>
</select>
```

Now that your `country-component` is ready to let parent know when a country is selected.

Define output parameter at your parent component like:

```
<country-component (ngModelOptions)="{standalone:true}" name="" (countrySelected)="enableSubmit($event)"></country-component>
```

and define a function at your parent component

```
submitEnabled : bool = false;

enableSubmit(event: any){
    this.submitEnabled = true;
}
```

and bind your button to your `submitEnabled` variable.

```
<button [disabled]="!submitEnabled">Submit</button>
```